# why does pipenv installs python when the required versions is already installed by pyenv?

Tags: python

I am trying to clean up a messy workstation for all my reportees so we use **pyenv** to drive our python versions.
I installed python using

```
pyenv install 3.11.3
```

Located correctly within

```
/Users/rfk851/.pyenv/shims/python3
```

I am now trying to install **pipenv** which internally uses this exact version. But its again downloading python 3.11.3 and installing it globally at this location which undoes the very usage of **pyenv**

```
/usr/local/bin/python3
```

IS there any way I can stop pipenv from re-downloading python and "use" the one downloaded by **pyenv**?